# What's the difference in asp tags if we use <asp:BoundField /> or <asp:BoundField> and </asp:BoundField>?

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm starting to understand ASP code through a complete project written by others. In the aspx file, there is code like

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                                HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Location">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
```

. but if I put

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Lcation" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Location" />
```

, it's also works. I'm wondering about if there is difference between those ending tags with/without the name of beginning. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the only difference is that the first version indicated a header alignment twice (in two different ways) and the second version eliminated that duplication.

Comment: Yeah I was guessing so about the duplication in first case. Thanks David.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's called a self-closing tag.

They're identical.

Comment: Note: Self-closing tags are identical in asp, but are not always identical in plain html.  For example, I recommend against self-closing `<script>` tags.